# Vim disable SpecialKey highlighting

Tags: vim

I use `set list lcs=tab:\❘\` to display tab indenting, and subtly set the color to be slightly lighter than my background. However, CursorLine seems to highlight these in white, which is unwanted. What can I do so that the color does not highlight, but stays the same?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do. Vim will use the foreground color of `CursorLine`, or `Normal` if the former isn't defined. It currently doesn't "mix" the color definitions from `SpecialKey` and `CursorLine`. You could suggest changing this behavior on the [vim_dev mailing list](http://www.vim.org/community.php).

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution [here](https://developpaper.com/vim-tip-set-the-spaces-and-tab-characters-visible-and-customize-the-color-of-the-characters-displayed/) and it works for me

```
:highlight MyTabSpace guifg=darkgrey ctermfg=darkgrey
:match MyTabSpace /\t\| /
```